Solving vulnerabilities with peer dependency vs override
After vulnerability reports, I might to be able to solve the issue with just an updated version of the dependency in the peerDependencies section, while on some other times I have to install on the overrides section.
Can someone explain why/when does this happen ?
I guess it would make more sense only to use the overrides section.
Thanks for your time
